# Ideals of Nagata Trivialization

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then the Nagata idealization/trivialization construction $R(+)M$ is well known. Suppose $J$ is an ideal of $R(+)M$. Then it is known that $J=I(+)C$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ defined by the first coordinate of $J$ and $C$ is a submodule of $M$ defined by the second coordinate of $J$.

QUESTION: I am unable to show that $I(+)C$ is contained in $J$.

This should be easy but i am missing something simple. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @user114539 Your claim is wrong! The ideal generated by $(2,2)$ in $\mathbb Z(+)2\mathbb Z$ is not of that form.

Comment: @user114539 Actually it's not your claim: it's Theorem 25.1(1) from Huckaba, *Commutative Rings with Zero Divisors*. (This doesn't change anything: the claim is wrong.)

Comment: oh wow, sorry i did not see your last comment, i was looking at the same reference. Nice to know that this is false, i tried to play with it but did not succeed, and thought there might be some simple manipulation that i was missing.